# AttributeError: module 'salt.modules' has no attribute 'cp'

Tags: salt-stack

The CP command from the terminal is working as expected via
`salt "*" cp_push ....` works as expected from the master terminal. However using the command in an execution module fails with:

```
AttributeError: module 'salt.modules' has no attribute 'cp'
```

Salt is imported in the execution module via:

```
import salt
```

The function is being called as:

```
salt.modules.cp.push(path=str(latest_report))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a work around.
used:

```
salt.modules.cmdmod.run("salt-call cp.push *desired path*, shell="powershell")
```

Using powershell solved a plethora of other errors in default Command Prompt